# Accessing key with space from JSON in HTML attribute (Angular 10 Property binding)

Tags: html, json, angular, binding

I am trying to access a JSON key value( with space) inside a HTML attribute. My page is on Angular 10 version and I am binding `src` attribute to a key in JSON.

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">    
  <img [src]="element.Player Name"/>   
</td>
```

JSON

```
{
"Name": "Richard",
"Player Name": "https://sampleURl/example.jpg"
}
```

Here 'Player Name' is the key with space. I tried:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">    
  <img [src]="element[Player Name]"/>   
</td>
```

This works for normal binding but not here.
Thanks for any help

Comment: I believe `element['Player Name']` works. `element.Player_Name` may also be worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to bind using an actual string (and not something for angular to translate), use 'actual string', in your case:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">    
  <img [src]="element['Player Name']"/>   
</td>
```